# Ldap database recovery after server crash

Tags: ldap

so my server crashed and my backup is a couple of weeks old :(. 
so....

I have the old files that can be found in /var/lib/ldap

How can i recover my db, or export them in a ldif files.

Tnx all
Zlatko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming an openldap instance here, but the **slapcat** utility may prove useful.  A few years ago I was running an ldap instance that was frequently blowing up its indices, so its fairly common to **slapcat** the database to a big ldif file, move out the db files, and then **slapadd** to regenerate the db from the ldif.

Answer (score 0):

One of our machines running a third party system that used LDAP for authentication amongst other things has upset its LDAP setup before now (I've never worked out *how* as there are generally no graceless stops that I can account for).

The following has always worked to sort it:

1. make sure the ldap daemon is stopped:
   `/etc/init.d/ldap stop`
2. take a backup of the curent state just in case:
   `cd /var/lib/ldap-dpp/`
   `rmdir -rfv /home/tmp_ldap/`
   `mkdir /home/tmp_ldap`
   `cp * /home/tmp_ldap/ -av`
3. run the recovery tool to rerun/clear out the transactions in the log:
   `/usr/sbin/slapd_db_recover -v`
4. restart the ldap service:
   `/etc/init.d/ldap start`

(replacing any paths with correct ones for your system, of course)

If this fails, you have a backup from step 2 to roll back to ready to try something else. It might be worth taking a full system backup now before taking any steps to fix the issue, in case the attempts to fix things make something worse.